# Matlab: How to publish a report on including mutiple.m files

Tags: matlab, report, publish

how to publish a report on including mutiple.m files? For example, I have 3 .m files and 1 principal .m file that call others files and run specified codes. Each file has your own plots and terminal information. I would like to gererate the publish report including all files executed. In some tests, the publish report generate only the main file where I click the publish button.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tryied the [publishdepfun function](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33476-publish-dependent-and-called-functions/content/publishdepfun.m)?

Comment: I haven´t tried yet, I just click on the publish button, but this option publishes only the current file. I will try to understand better this function. Thanks a lot. Best regards